# C++ Poco - How to create a vector of NotificationQueue's?

Tags: c++, vector, notifications, poco-libraries, deleted-functions

I want to create a *Notification Center*, where I handle all the `notifications` to `threads`.

I can't tell on the software boot how many `notification` queues I would need. It may vary during `run-time`.

So I've created this (code simplified):

```
#include <vector>
#include "Poco/Notification.h"
#include "Poco/NotificationQueue.h"

using Poco::Notification;
using Poco::NotificationQueue;

int main()
{
    std::vector<NotificationQueue> notificationCenter;
    NotificationQueue q1;
    NotificationQueue q2;
    notificationCenter.push_back(q1); //ERROR: error: use of deleted function ‘Poco::NotificationQueue::NotificationQueue(const Poco::NotificationQueue&)’
    notificationCenter.push_back(q2);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the `error: use of deleted function ‘Poco::NotificationQueue::NotificationQueue(const Poco::NotificationQueue&)’`

Which I understand. I cannot copy or assign a `NotificationQueue`.

**Question:**

Is there any way I can handle a vector of `NotificationQueue`'s without creating them statically?

Comment: `std::vector` requires to operate on [copyable types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which `Poco::NotificationQueue` apparently isn't.

Comment: NotificationQueue has no copy constructor, push_back in your context will create a copy. Create a vector of pointers (smart) to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `@arynaq` comment, a vector of pointers will make the job:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include "Poco/Notification.h"
#include "Poco/NotificationQueue.h"

using Poco::Notification;
using Poco::NotificationQueue;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<NotificationQueue>> notificationCenter;
    std::shared_ptr<NotificationQueue> q1 = std::make_shared<NotificationQueue>();
    std::shared_ptr<NotificationQueue> q2 = std::make_shared<NotificationQueue>();

    notificationCenter.push_back(q1);
    notificationCenter.push_back(q2);

    return 0;
}
```